# Mapbox js directions, how to set origin to track user location

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using Mapbox JS directions. Everything works fine, but I want to setOrigin (starting point) to always track current user location. I know I can do it "manualy" to set something like:

```
geolocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
 directions.setOrigin([e.coords.longitude, e.coords.latitude]); 
});
```

But there must me some other method (built in)? I saw "steps" option, but it does nothing. This is my current code:

```
var directions = new MapboxDirections({
  accessToken: 'TOKEN',
  unit: 'metric', // Use the metric system to display distances.
  profile: 'mapbox/driving', // Set the initial profile to walking.
  container: 'directions', // Specify an element thats not the map container.
  //  controls: {instructions: false},
  bearing: true,
  steps: true,
  voice_instructions: true,
  controls: {
    inputs: false,
    instructions: true,
    profileSwitcher: true
  }
});

map.on('load', function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      directions.setOrigin([position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude]);
    });
  }

  directions.setDestination([13.625068664574526, 45.128315601980965]); // On load, set the destination to "Montreal, Quebec".
});
directions.on('route', function(e) {
  console.log(e.route); // Logs the current route shown in the interface.
});
```

edit: Actually, I am searching for turn by turn navigation i javascript SDK.

Thank you!

Comment: How about using [Geolocation.watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) that listens to the current position?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, actually I am doing that, I am tracking user location and showing marker on user current geolocation. But that doesnt interact with Mapbox Directions (turn instructions do not change, mapbox directions API returns a route and that route is static, fixed). What I want to achieve is that origin marker (default A) follows user current position.

Comment: This library only gets you the route detail. What you need to do is to evaluate the current location and user bearing against `steps[].geometry` in the response and if it matches the location, you can show the `steps[].maneuver.instruction`. You know when to show the next maneuver when `steps[].geometry` is almost finished.  You can evaluate the location by creating a [circle](http://turfjs.org/docs/#circle) around the current location and see if that [intersects](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanWithin) with each geometry.